# Recovering ETC from a contract (not DAO) / running MIST

Tags: wallets, ethereum-classic

The issue I have is that I have some ETC in an old wallet from the pre-fork time. Most of them are located in a contract with positive balance shown using an explorer.

I am able to enter my wallet from online wallets but there are only 3 etc as balance. I cannot liquidate contract to move the rest of etc to the main address.
Can it be done by online wallet and how? tried access contract on https://classicetherwallet.com/#contracts but I don't know these Json strings mystyery...

Another option is to use standalone wallet, I downloaded MIST and Ethereum wallet, got the wallet imported on geth but none of them is downloading blocks. NAT ports are open but it does not help. Tried to download the chain by torrent but no one is seeding.

What can be done to access my contract?

Answer (score -1):

```
[{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_dth","type":"address"}],"name":"calculateWithdraw","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"escapeHatch","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_additionalSeconds","type":"uint256"}],"name":"extendClosingTime","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_account","type":"address"}],"name":"getPaidOut","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getWHGDonationAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_account","type":"address"}],"name":"getMyBalance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"changeOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"claimRemaining","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"deposit","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_beneficiary","type":"address"},{"name":"_percentageWHG","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_v","type":"uint8"},{"name":"_r","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"proxyWithdraw","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getTotalFunds","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_beneficiary","type":"address"},{"name":"_percentageWHG","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_whg_donation","type":"address"},{"name":"_daoBalanceSnapshotAddress","type":"address"},{"name":"_escapeAddress","type":"address"},{"name":"_remainingBeneficiary","type":"address"}],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"dth","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"beneficiary","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"percentageWHG","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"withdrawType","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Withdraw","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_depositor","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_allowed","type":"bool"}],"name":"CertifiedDepositorsChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"EscapeCalled","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RemainingClaimed","type":"event"}]
```

Comment: thanks i've tried that selected withdraw, left the amount 0 as suggested per wallet and the transaction went in but its 0 and nothing happened. http://gastracker.io/tx/0x3474a8074c9d5deec991ecd4eae84c3e58058128a4de60162b4e02a00d9264c5 tried again, with amount of 127,did nothing to gas price left it at 34k but all I got was:
http://etherhub.io/tx/undefined no track of transaction. transaction submitted but no tx any help?

Comment: any help, please? cannot find the solution, amount moved is always 0 etc

Comment: have you tried using parity?

Comment: yes, withdraw parity and nothing. somehow it always sends transaction FROM wallet to CONTRACT not otherwise.

Comment: Did you check that you actually have ETC in the contract?